# why is my carousel margined to right

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-4

Im using carousel on my website, and it's somehow not aligned with row, but is instead margined like 40px to the right

I've tried using margin:0, margin-left:0, but nothing works.

Also everytime it scrolls through next images, it gets thrown out of a row for some reason.

Any help?

**my html code**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="fff">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="random img" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>random caption</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**my css code**

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
}
.thumbnails li > .fff .caption {
background: #fff !important;
padding: 10px
}
ul.thumbnails {
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.caption h4 {
color: #444;
}
.caption p {
color: #999;
}
li {
list-style-type: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.page-header, .control-box {
    text-align: center;
}
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
.caption {
    word-break: break-all;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you make a _real_ snippet so we can run that and see what's going on? Or do you have a working example somewhere public?

Comment: try removing .col-md-4 on li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS Rule:

```
ul.thumbnails {
  padding:0;
}
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

**Use :**

```
body {
  margin:0;
}

.thumbnails {
  padding: 0;
}
```